# MySQL Select with higher priority

Tags: mysql

I have a query like that:

```
SELECT id, title
FROM tbl_item
WHERE id!=477
  AND (projectid=172 OR styleid=66)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 4;
```

How can I order the item by same projectid first (list all projectid 172), then same styleid (66) even if the timestamp of styleid is greater.

```
id  projectid styleid timestamp
475 172       66      1401660000
459 172       66      1398981600
458 167       66      1398636000
456 172       64      1397685600
449  63       66      1394665200
444 167       66      1391727600
411 113       66      1386630000
408  62       66      1385938800
407 159       66      1385938800
387 159       66      1375826400
```

With my snapshot above, my desire result is merge of two queries:
Query 1: SELECT id FROM tbl_item WHERE projectid=172;
Query 2: SELECT id FROM tbl_item WHERE styleid=66;

Desire result ids: 475,459,456,458

The first 3 ids (475,459,456) is result of #1, and the 458 is result of #2 (LIMIT 4 results)

Thank you!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: maybe you can post snapshot of your table result.

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. Wouldn't inner SELECT or better ORDER BY (maybe using CASE) do the trick?

Comment: I want the 1st priority in query is projectid, 2nd priority is styleid. If the same projectid is lower than 4, it will choose the same styleid.

Comment: @Niang I've just added the snapshot. Help me :'(

Comment: @hatxi But please try to read your question again and explain it better

Comment: @Niang I modified the question, does it better to understand :(

Comment: Try `ORDER BY ID, STYLEID, TIMESTAMP`. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis it listed ids with same style higher.

Comment: OK - then add `ASC` or `DESC` as needed after each field - for example, `ORDER BY ID ASC, STYLEID DESC, TIMESTAMP ASC`. Change things around until you get what you want. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis `id` is not the same as `projectid` in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple columns to the `ORDER BY`, they are prioritised from left to right see [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

```
  SELECT id, projectid, styleid, timestamp
    FROM tbl_item
   WHERE ...
ORDER BY projectid, styleid, timestamp DESC;
```

N.B. You do not need to `SELECT` the columns used by the `ORDER BY`, I have just included them for clarity.

**UPDATE**

From your update to the question, it can be done bespokely like this

```
  SELECT id, projectid, styleid, timestamp
    FROM tbl_item
   WHERE projectid=172 
      OR styleid=66
ORDER BY projectid=172 DESC,
         projectid != 172 AND styleid=66 DESC,
         timestamp DESC
   LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: Wrong, with the styleid=66 and projectid=200, it have higher order :(

Comment: @Hatxi Then I still do not know what you want. You really need to make your question clearer, by providing a list of rows in the order you want them to appear. As Bob suggested above you can use ASC/DESC for each column e.g. `ORDER BY projectid DESC, styleid DESC, timestamp DESC`.

Comment: I want a query to list the item by same projectid FIRST, THEN same styleid. The same projectid is most priority. Maybe my query is wrong? Or use other function?

Comment: No problem.. if you are having trouble wording the question diagrams and lists are always useful!